# What settings should WebSettings set for Webview (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-webview, settings

I don't really know much about web security stuff but I do want to make sure some settings that should be done are done.

What kind of general settings methods should I perform for better security or performance or something else? Short explanations would be great but just the code is awesome too.

I currently have these:

```java
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new ViewClient());

private class ViewClient extends WebViewClient...
```

Thank you.

Comment: you should not expect much security or performance from WebView, and there is not easy way to achieve it. In general - don't change the settings you don't need.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you! I won't change anything then